# How to reuse the web client for HtmlProvider?

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data, fsharp.data.typeproviders

I load multiple pages using the same type provider, [HtmlProvider](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlProvider.html):

```fs
type Article = HtmlProvider<"https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giraffe">

let sheepArticle = Article.Load "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheep"
let koalaArticle = Article.Load "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/koala"
let pandaArticle = Article.Load "https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/panda"
...
```

Is it anyhow possible to configure the provider so that the web client underneath is reused there?

I haven't found nothing on that in the docs. I do a lot of similar calls, so that would be a significant optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to configure the `HtmlProvider` to do this automatically behind the scenes, but you can easily create your own `WebClient` to download the pages and then use the `Parse` method of the provided type (rather than using `Load` to download and parse it):

```
type Article = HtmlProvider<"https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/giraffe">

let wc = new WebClient()
let sheepArticle = Article.Parse(wc.DownloadString("https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheep"))
let koalaArticle = Article.Parse(wc.DownloadString("https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/koala"))
let pandaArticle = Article.Parse(wc.DownloadString("https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/panda"))
```